# How can I do this SQL in Query builder laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

How can I do this SQL in Query builder laravel?

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', created_at) AS hour_stump,
  (extract(hour FROM created_at)::int / 60) AS min_slot,
  count(*),
  max(e4) as kwh
FROM energydata_1001
WHERE api_key_value= 'YaB8JCcE'
AND date(created_at) >= '2020-11-30 23:59:59'
AND date(created_at) <= '2020-12-29 00:00:00'
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

Can anyone help me, because i'm new in laravel.
Thank you.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: out of curiosity how does `DATE(created_at)` differ from `date_trunc('day', created_at)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a line by line equivalent.

| SQL | Builder |
| --- | --- |
| ``` SELECT date_trunc('day', created_at) AS hour_stump, (extract(hour FROM created_at)::int / 60) AS min_slot, count(*), max(e4) as kwh FROM energydata_1001 WHERE api_key_value= 'YaB8JCcE' AND date(created_at) >= '2020-11-30 23:59:59' AND date(created_at) <= '2020-12-29 00:00:00' GROUP BY 1, 2 ORDER BY 1, 2; ``` | ``` DB::query() ->selectRaw("date_trunc('day', created_at) AS hour_stump") /* day must be in single quotes because it's a raw expression. */ ->selectRaw('(extract(hour FROM created_at)::int / 60) AS min_slot') ->selectRaw('count(*)') ->selectRaw('max(e4) as kwh') ->from('energydata_1001') ->where('api_key_value', '=', 'YaB8JCcE') ->whereRaw("date(created_at) >= ?", ['2020-11-30 23:59:59']) ->whereRaw("date(created_at) <= ?", ['2020-12-29 00:00:00']) ->groupByRaw('1, 2') ->orderByRaw('1, 2') ->get(); ``` |

- `selectRaw` must be used instead of `select` because your select statement has functions and casting in it (date_trunc, extract, ::int, count, max). `selectRaw` supports raw sql expressions.
- Same thing with `whereRaw` because of the `date()` function.
- `groupByRaw` must be used because you're not grouping by a selected column.
- `orderByRaw` must be used because you're not ordering by a selected column.

This could be written a bit differently.

- Instead of `DB::query()->selectRaw(...->from('energydata_1001')`, you could write `DB::table('energydata_1001')->selectRaw(...`. I chose to write it that way to make an easier comparison. The generated SQL won't change.
- Instead of `whereRaw("date(created_at) <= ?", ['2020-11-30 23:59:59'])` you could use `whereDate('created_at', '<=', '2020-11-30 23:59:59')`. The difference lies in the generated SQL. `whereDate` casts the column to a date instead of using the `date()` function when using PostgreSQL.

  - `whereRaw("date(created_at) >= ?", ['2020-11-30 23:59:59'])`
    translates to `where/and date(created_at) >= '2020-11-30 23:59:59'`.
  - `whereDate('created_at', '>=', '2020-11-30 23:59:59')`
    translates to `where/and created_at::date >= '2020-11-30 23:59:59'` in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with query builder, like :

```
$users = DB::select('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);
```

With eloquent :

```
$user = User::select(DB::raw('select * from users where active = ?', [1]))->get();
```